# Android Emulator Doesn't show the result of Web service and giving the result "false" instead of addition

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am consuming a web service "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" on android and try to access its method "CelsiusToFahrenheit" and added the internet permission in the manifest file but when I ran the project the emulator shows the false result instead of conversion of celsius to fahrenheit. Any help will be appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
public class FinalKsoap extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
public static final String URL =  
          "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
public static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
TextView tv,tv1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text01); 
       tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text02);
       SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
       Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");
       SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new
            SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
       soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

       AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL); 
       try
    {

            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            tv.setText("Status : " + result);
    }
   catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tv1.setText("Hellooooooo"); 

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake. As far as I remember the getResponse() method always returns only true (command success) or false (command failed).

If you want the data returned by the web service you have to use the following code:

```
public static void test() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
    System.out.println(result); // prints "89.6"
    if (resultsRequestSOAP != null) {
        System.out.println(resultsRequestSOAP);
      Object o = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("CelsiusToFahrenheitResult");
      System.out.println(o); // prints "89.6"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert. I have added it as, Object response = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("Celsius");
     tv.setText(response.toString()); but still get the same error

Comment: May be you should just use my sample code instead (just updated).

Comment: Again thank you Robert but it still does show the false on screen instead of actual result

Comment: Then may be your used ksoap library is defect.

Comment: yes I have the compatibility problem. I used android 2.1 and project runs. Now it shows "Status : Error" on screen instead of desired value.